# Получить гейтвей зная адресс хоста и маску (Python3 ipaddress)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сеть, ansible

Добрый вечер.

Составляю генерацию к host_vars файлов в Ansible.

Имеется на входе "сырой" файл с будущими адресами хостов (будет генерироваться /etc/network/interface файл по шаблону), маска всегда постояная - 255.255.255.128 так так же, как и гейтвей - *.*.*.1

*host_vars.yml.j2*

```
---

sys_hostname: "{{ cfg_hostname }}"
sys_type: "{{ type }}"

sys_eth0_ipv4_address: "{{ tb_eth0 }}"
sys_eth0_ipv4_gateway: "{{ tb_eth0_gw }}"
sys_eth0_ipv4_netmask: "255.255.255.128"
```

Файл с сырыми значениями:

*raw_host_vars*

```
ES:TB-MT:SiteHostName-1:10.58.11.111
ES:TB-MT:SiteHostName-2:10.58.12.111
ES:TB-MT:SiteHostName-3:10.58.13.111
```

Скрипт, который будет генерировать файлы

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import yaml
import ipaddress

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Template

ENV = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates'))

with open('./raw_host_vars') as file:
    raw_host_vars = file.read().split("\n")

template = ENV.get_template("host_vars.yml.j2")

for line in raw_host_vars:
    iso = line.split(":")[0]
    type = line.split(":")[1]
    cfg_hostname = line.split(":")[2]
    tb_eth0 = line.split(":")[3]
    tb_eth0_gw = # Нужно сформировать гейтвей по шаблону \*.\*.\*.1
                 # изменить только последний октет

    print(template.render(cfg_hostname=cfg_hostname,
                          iso=iso,
                          type=type,
                          tb_eth0=tb_eth0,
                          tb_eth0_gw=tb_eth0_gw))
# End of script
```

Как сформировать новый адрес (гейтвей) из имеющихся данных о подсети и адреса самого хоста исользую модуль **ipaddress** (документация практически не содержит примеров)?

Рабочий хак:

```
tb_eth0_gw = ".".join(line.split(":")[2].split(".")[:3])+".1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если gateway это первый адрес в подсети:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> mask = ipaddress.ip_address('255.255.255.128')
>>> host = ipaddress.ip_address('10.58.11.111')
>>> gateway = ipaddress.ip_address(int(host) & int(mask)) + 1
>>> gateway
IPv4Address('10.58.11.1')
```